# Abrir e fechar textarea com o mesmo botão

Tags: javascript, html

HTML do `textarea` com o botão para abrir:

```
<input type="button" name="abrir" class="botao">
<div id="comentario" style="display:none">
<textarea id="Observacao" name="Observacao" style="color: black;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Para abrir o botão estou a usar o seguinte `script`:

```
$('input[name=abrir]').mousedown(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if( e.button != 1 ) { 
      $('#comentario').show();
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Mas pretendia que ao clicar novamente no botão voltasse a fechar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No lugar do `.show` utilize o `.toggle`,

Ve documentação [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

veja o exemplo:

```js
$('input[name=abrir]').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.button != 1) {
    $('#comentario').toggle();
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" name="abrir" value='Abrir / Fechar' class="botao">
<div id="comentario" style="display:none">
  <textarea id="Observacao" name="Observacao" style="color: black;"></textarea>
</div>
```